# How to define a special template for a product option in the account / order view page?

Tags: orders, template, custom-options, invoice

I have implemented a module to have a custom input product option type (following this [tutorial](http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/custom-input-types-custom-options))

This module defines 2 different template for the frontend :

- one for the catalog view
- another one used both for the shopping cart, the "view order" page of the client account/oderhistory and invoice. This template uses product option customview possibility.

I would like to define a special template for the "order view" page / invoice?
Is it possible?

my layout files is : (app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/custoptiontype.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.options">
        <action method="addOptionRenderer">
            <type>filesstate</type>
            <block>custoptiontype/catalog_product_view_options_type_filesstate</block>
            <template>custoptiontype/catalog/product/view/options/type/filesstate.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

the called class

```
<?php
class Mine_Custoptiontype_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Options_Type_Filesstate
        extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Abstract
{
}
?>
```

the catalog template is defined by app/design/frontend/base/default/template/custoptiontype/catalog/product/view/options/type/filesstate.phtml

Regarding the second template (option customview), the template is in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/custoptiontype/options/customview/filesstate.phtml

called by

```
<?php
class Mine_Custoptiontype_Model_Catalog_Product_Option_Type_Filesstatetype
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Type_Default
{
    public function isCustomizedView()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function getCustomizedView($optionInfo)
    {
        $customizeBlock = new Mine_Custoptiontype_Block_Options_Type_Customview_Filesstate();
        $customizeBlock->setInfo($optionInfo);
        return $customizeBlock->toHtml();
    }
}
?>
```

with

```
<?php
class Mine_Custoptiontype_Block_Options_Type_Customview_Filesstate
    extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected $_template = 'custoptiontype/options/customview/filesstate.phtml';
}
?>
```

thank you for your help,

Alex

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you will have to override the renderer templates, I see no hook into the rendering of the options there.